# Shorter expression for if (a) b=a; in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to use a lot of following expressions with long variable names.

```
if (a) b = a;
```

Is there is Javascript any shorter way how to write this?

Comment: `a && b = a` is terser, but not necessarily more readable.

Comment: That seems like a pretty short expression already.  Why the desire to save a keystroke or two?  Typing code into an editor isn't the hard part, supporting that code later is the hard part.  It's a lot easier to support if it's clear and understandable than if it's clever and compact.

Comment: Yes, explain your reason for wanting something "shorter".  (Note that you'll never make the statement shorter than two names.  The difference between 2 names long and 3 seems not worth the effort.)

Comment: @HotLicks 2 vs 3 long names worth the effort, also speed up writing.

Comment: Maybe you should work on coming up with shorter names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't get much shorter than that, some folks have helpfully put slightly terser alternatives in the comments to your question, although the point about maintainability versus readability is a good one to bear in mind too.

That said, I guess if your variable names are very long, as you say they are, then there is scope for reducing it by mentioning each variable name only once. e.g. your example could in practice be:

```
if (really_really_really_really_long_var_a) really_really_really_really_long_var_b = really_really_really_really_long_var_a;
```

I suppose I can see how that's a little annoying and possibly even a little unreadable if done a lot.

Best I can think of is to declare a little helper function, perhaps:

```
var equate = function(a, b) {
    if (a) b = a;
}
```

and then your long line above can be shortened a little as you only have to mention each variable once, e.g.

```
equate(really_really_really_really_long_var_a, really_really_really_really_long_var_b);
```

I'm not entirely sure I like it, but at your discretion, if it shortens the code and maintains some level of readability, then perhaps it'd help?

Comment: This is a really good answer and i tend to go that Readability is more important that size of code